# ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a dynamic query using  procedure. The input parameter is of timestamp data type.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST
(p_party_eff_dt_in mina_owner.party_to_party.effective_two_dt%TYPE)

select to_timestamp(p_party_eff_dt_in,'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from <table>
```

gives the following error

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Please help

**Edit:**

```
P_PARTY_EFF_DT_IN :='03-JUL-04 04.34.50.198000000 AM'; –
```

Comment: what is the value of p_party_eff_dt_in

Comment: If the input parameter already is a `timestamp`, why the `to_timestamp`?

Comment: None of this makes sense. This is not the actual code you're running so it is hard for to understand what you're trying to achieve. The least you can do is post a working reproducible test case with sample input. Plus an explanation of the logic, like why you're casting a TIMESTAMP parameter to a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: P_PARTY_EFF_DT_IN :='03-JUL-04 04.34.50.198000000 AM';

Answer (score 1):

You are using a format mask that does not match your input string.

Assuming that in `'03-JUL-04' '03'` is the day and `'04'` stays for 2004, you need:

```
select to_timestamp('03-JUL-04 04.34.50.198000000 AM', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.FF9 PM') from dual
```